# Cannot find the maximum ratings for the output current

Tags: operational-amplifier, maximum-ratings

For the part of a circuit shown below I'm using an [LT1007](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/100737fbs.pdf) but couldn't find any information about the maximum current output can sink or source.

[image]

They have written every tiny detail but the maximum output current is not there. Can anybody else see or infer it from the data-sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that information is given in the "Output Short-Circuit Current vs Time" plot in the bottom right corner of page 7 of the datasheet.

[image]

I guess I'd interpret that as this op-amp isn't made to source/sink a lot of output current.  I'd probably play it safe and keep it under 10mA at most.  If you need more, try a different amplifier (a power type perhaps), or you could add your own totem-pole BJT output stage to boost your sink/source current.

[image]

Comment: Given the R2 in OP's circuit, the external totem pole is probably not needed.

Comment: @ThePhoton Ah, true, didn't consider they had a series 1k there.

Comment: @nonya_business - Welcome to the site :-) Please note that one of the site rules requires you to correctly [reference](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) the original source for text/images/photos etc., which you copy from elsewhere e.g. in this case, the schematic diagram. Please edit your answer to include the required link to the original. Thanks. (I suggest reading the [tour] and [help] to see more about the site and how it operates.)

Answer (score 2):

You could deduce it from the fact that its output is current limited, the maximum power dissipation, and the fact that its output impedance is 70Ω. However, you could also look at the graphs in the datasheet.

[image: Datasheet graphs]

It looks like less than 20mA @125°C